# Tkinter: Listbox drag selection

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter, mouse, coordinates

I am having problems with the way that the right button gets its selection. I am not good with coordinates so i dont know how to reverse the way i am selecting. I would like to scroll the listbox selection the way the mouse is going, not the reverse like it is right now. I would simply like it to select the next item in the listbox when moving the mouse down/up.

```
from Tkinter import *

def _select(y):
    row = lb.nearest(y)
    lb.selection_clear(0, END)
    lb.selection_set(row)

def _b2motion(x, y):
    lb.scan_dragto(x, y)
    _select(y)
    return 'break'


root = Tk()

sb = Scrollbar(root)
lb =Listbox(root, width=20,yscrollcommand=sb.set)

lb.bind('<B3-Motion>', lambda e: _b2motion(e.x, e.y))
sb.config(command=lb.yview)

lb.grid(row=0,column=0)
sb.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+S)


for x in range(50):
    lb.insert(END, x)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you flip the sign on the y in the motion box that will change the direction of scrolling.  Divide by an integer if you need it slower, I liked 3.

```
def _b2motion(x, y):
    lb.scan_dragto(x, (-y/3)) #here
    _select(y)
    return 'break'
```

I am not sure what the rest of your problem is... are you trying to replicate what the left button does with the right button?

Comment: I really like how i can slow the scrolling, but my problem is the big jump of the list when you right click towards the bottom of the program

Comment: @Crispy It seems like this is unavoidable using `scan_dragto`. Try `lb.yview_scroll((y/100), 'units')` instead, which scrolls the window. Again the 100 is a scaling